# Why can Jenkins not find python and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, windows-11

### Problem:

I have a Jenkins controller installed on a Windows 11 laptop, which somehow cannot execute Python scripts. Whether I use `py` or `python` it always outputs the same error message, which says that `py / python` cannot be found or is spelled incorrectly. This is roughly translated from German. I don't know the English message word for word. The actual error message is this:

```
Der Befehl "py" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

which is also peculiar, because German is only defined as the secondary language of this computer. But it might be because the initial setup was done in german, but I digress. This error message usually means that the path to the Python executable is missing or unknown, right?

### Steps taken:

I have already tried the following:

1. I checked if there is something wrong with my Jenkinsfile, however it would neither run the example pipeline from the official Jenkins documentation nor just `python --version`.
2. I have tried various ways of calling the script in the Jenkinsfile, `bat 'py ...'`, `bat 'python ...'`, `bat 'python3 ...'` and none of them worked.
3. I have checked if the `$PATH` variable has the Python path in it. It does.
4. I have tried executing the Python script via cmd from the same location as Jenkins. It worked.
5. I have installed the ShiningPanda plugin and added the path to the directory containing `python.exe` and `py.exe`. It still spat out the same error.

### Additional info, which might be useful

I am executing this pipeline directly on the controller, and I am aware that this is not optimal. However this is just for testing purposes and a proof of concept.

Another thing that might have something to do with it is that I have installed Jenkins as LocalSystem, because my user account is not authorised to install it as a LocalService.

I can execute `.bat` files from the Jenkinsfile, so nothing is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: When environment variables do you see via (Manage Jenkins -> System information)? Is python on the path? Of course, you might also try specification of the full path to python.exe as well.

Comment: All your manual test is via cmd, which has its bashrc, setting up env variable and alias etc. That is not something the jenkins controller see. The bash script is likely the most independent solution but you may need every env variable /aliasing you need in that bash script. WIthin the script, you want to be calling your python script with the python executable's absolute path too.

Comment: @JonSG no, the python path is not there, i have tried adding it from the Jenkinsfile, but i might have done that wrong. I put this into my Jenkinsfile:
    environment {
        PATH = "C:/Users/path/to/python:$PATH"
    }

Comment: Path parts are seperated by a semi-colon `";"` in windows usually, I think you might have a solon there.

Comment: @JonSG Oh yeah, thats it, thanks. I do now have another error message though, which says that the specified program cannot be run. Do i have to give it permissions somewhere?

Comment: hmm, not a windows permissions expert but I agree it sounds like a windows permission thing. Perhaps try a new question mentioning what you did here and someone will be able to help get you past the next hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Jenkins controller has its own PATH environment variable. Python was not added in mine, so in order to get it working I had to add the following to my `Jenkinsfile`. I put it before the stages:

```
environment {
    PATH = "C:/path/to/dir/containing/python.exe;$PATH"
}
```